# Can using higher rated battery damage device?

Tags: laptop, battery

I am in need of  a battery for my Lenovo 3000 Y410 Laptop. It's installed battery has voltage rating of 10.8v. But the shop i've consulted has only a battery of 11.1v rating.

Should I buy the battery? I mean, Does using that battery can damage my laptop?

An answer with some good source from hardware vendor will be very much helpful. *Please do not just put your opinion*.  Because I do not see any difference in your opinion and my opinion. My opinion is also "It is bad". But I need some reliable source.

Comment: If both are Li-ion batteries, then 11.1 is just an advertising gimmick.  Each Li-ion cell varies from 4.3V (at full charge) down to about 3.4V at maximum safe discharge.  But the discharge curve isn't linear, it is about 3.6V (three in series are 10.8V) for most of the useful range of charge.  Some companies call their batteries 3.7V (three in series are 11.1V) just to make them sound better, but it's the same voltage with the same chemistry.  Whether you want to buy a battery from a company engaged in deceptive marketing is a different question entirely.

Comment: @BenVoigt No advertising gimick.  Lenovo itself sells multiple batteries for different models rated at 11.1v http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/site.workflow:SimpleSiteSearch?lang=en&q=11.1v&cc=us&ff=2 none of which is for this particular laptop.  So unless you are saying that Lenovo itself is practicing those deceptive marketing techniques for only some of their battery sales, it would appear that even Lenovo believes there is enough of a difference.

Comment: @BonGart: Seems all the Lenovo search results for 11.1V are "Li" and for 10.8V are "Li-ion".  The chemistry difference, which requires a completely different charger circuit, is far FAR more important than the nominal voltage, since voltage varies substantially with charge state.  Marking Li-ion as 3.7V/cell is a marketing gimmick, but that's not what Lenovo is doing.

Comment: @BenVoigt No, I'm finding 10.8v LI-ion and 11.1v LI-Ion batteries listed at Lenovo.  check http://shop.lenovo.com/us/itemdetails/0A36292/460/A5EB9DB8B66C416083597E397599C2A4 and http://shop.lenovo.com/us/itemdetails/57Y6493/460/A5EB9DB8B66C416083597E397599C2A4

Comment: @BonGart: Yep, that's marketing gimmickry.

Comment: @BenVoigt so you can't even trust Lenovo and what they say, since they are practicing that same deceptive marketing technique... that's what you are saying, since they sell both 10.8v Li-ion batteries, and 11.1v Li-ion batteries.  Just trying to be clear about this.

Comment: @BonGart: All those batteries listed are 6 cell Li-ion, arranged with 3 in series.  That means they are actually the same voltage, regardless of what the marketing team put on the box.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alright.  So, I knew what I knew, but after reading and responding in here I wanted to break out the volt meter and test a few things.  Just to be sure.  But I'll get to that.

I've got a 2004 Toshiba Satellite A75 sitting up in the kitchen as the general purpose computer for me and the wife.  I've got three batteries for it.  Why?  Well, I've got the original (still holds a charge) and two replacements for those times when I might be away from a power outlet but still might want to use it.

The Original Toshiba battery is 14.8v/6450mAh.  The first replacement (I didn't purchase it) is a generic 14.8v/4400mAh.  The replacement I did purchase is a [RayOVac](http://www.rayovac.com/) made 14.4v/6600mAh battery.  It is sitting in the laptop at this moment, and is the battery I've used for more than a year now.

So, from **personal experience** I can say that using a battery with a slightly different voltage rating will **NOT HARM YOUR LAPTOP**.  Heck, we are talking about running a laptop on a battery that puts out 14+ volts, that NORMALLY runs on 19 volts DC from the power adapter.

Oh, and all three batteries are designated as Li-ion

Now, as to the testing.  I took a Li-ion battery from an LG phone... and the battery is designated as an LG battery (not a third party replacement) that is Li-ion and rated at 3.7v.  It tested at 3.71v.  So, I took a Li-ion battery from a Motorola phone.  It was rated at 3.6v.  It tested at 3.75v.  Interesting.  So, I took my stack of Li-ion batteries that I have for my Panasonic digital video camera.  The one that came with it (printed as a Panasonic battery) is rated 3.6v, and tests as 4.09v.  One of the replacements that is designated 3.7v tests at 4.11v.  Another replacement designated at 3.7v tests at 4.03v

[image: Batteries]

So, I checked the battery in the tester to make sure it was still good.  Then I re-calibrated it.  Then I tested a couple of DC power adapters just to be sure, and then rested all those same batteries. (**Edit** I also tested a mess of Alkaline AA batteries.  We keep a stockpile of new ones for cameras, Xbox360 controllers, etc.  All tested between 1.4 and 1.6 volts.)

So, again.  What am I saying?  I am saying there is NO problem with getting that battery.  Provided that the battery casing was made for your laptop... meaning it will actually fit properly in your laptop.  It is not going to hurt your laptop to use the 11.1v battery.  I repeat.  It is **not going to hurt your laptop** to use the 11.1v battery.

Comment: Yup. My personal experience is a HP laptop running fine with a 11.1V/8800mAh battery, when the original battery was 10.8V/4400mAh. It's not had a single power/battery problem in the 6 months I've been using it. These batteries have such widely varying voltages potentially even with the same rating that such a small gap makes no real difference... And for the record, they're both labelled Li-ion.

Comment: Of course, there's a higher chance it's not a 'genuine' (i.e. sourced from the laptop manufacturer) battery if the voltage rating is different. (@AnwarShah)

Comment: @Bob, yes It is not 'genuine', should i still buy it?

Comment: There you run into shaky ground, @AnwarShah. Just about anything can happen: it could not turn on, it could damage your laptop, it could work perfectly. There's no guarantee any two 'fake' batteries will work the same way, though it's common for them to have poorer performance than 'genuine' batteries, and will often not last as long. We can't give a definite answer for that, you'll  have to make a decision yourself (and perhaps ask others who have bought batteries from that shop/of that brand).

Comment: Take a look, the difference between 14.8 and 14.4 is exactly the difference between 3.6V per cell and 3.7V per cell (your pack uses 4 cells in series).  It is just a marketing issue.

Comment: @BenVoigt except in this case, your "marketing issue" is working in reverse.  The Toshiba stock battery is using the 3.7v model, while the replacement is using the 3.6v model... not the other way around.  So, who exactly is practicing deceptive marketing?  You say that the company selling the 11.1v replacement battery over the stock 10.8v must be the deceptive one... so does that make Toshiba the deceptive one in my case?

Comment: @BonGart: The more problematic deception is when the manufacturer claims you need to buy their battery at four times the price, because the third-party battery is the "wrong" voltage.  Which is right and which is wrong doesn't matter in the slightest, because all 3 cell series Li-ion battery packs are actually the same voltage.

Comment: -1: The specified voltage is not necessarily measured at no load/open circuit. And, your opinion + playing with a voltmeter – consulting any spec sheets = just your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually find 3.6v, 3.65v, 3.7v and 3.8v nominal voltage Li-ion cells. The slight voltage difference is due to variances in chemical composition from one cell to another. The manufactures original tooling date also has a bearing on the voltage rating. This is the rated average voltage of the cell at 0.2C load down to its cutoff voltage usually about 2.75V.

About 11-12 years ago Li-ions were only charged to 4.1V and the mean/average voltage under load was 3.6V. More recently those same 3.6V cells with an identical chemistry are usually re-labed as 3.7V depending on the manufacturer and the batteries prime use of application. The reason for the .1V increase is when you recharge those same cells to 4.2-4.25V instead of 4.1V the rated average voltage of the cell also increases some.

The assumption that it’s just a marketing gimmick, is completely incorrect

Answer (score 0):

If you search Google you will get different answers, but I can tell you from experience, that if you get a battery with a higher voltage rating it will not work correctly in the laptop, and it may harm your laptop, and the battery.  You need the correct voltage for your laptop.  Now if Lenovo has an option to a different battery, I would ask them.  The battery that you have is a 6 cell, check to see if they have an 8 cell.

Comment: Actually, you'd be looking for a 9 cell for extended capacity.  You can't have a 3-in-series configuration with 8 cells.

Comment: @BenVoigt you can have an 8 cell , 9 cell batteries.  Take a look at this http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007934%2050010418&IsNodeId=1&name=Lenovo

Comment: 8 cell battery packs exist, but they won't have 3 cells in series, so they will be the wrong voltage (either 7.2V or 14.4V).  The laptop in question can never use an 8 cell battery pack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can damage your laptop. But considering it's only 0.3V difference and assuming your laptop would actually turn on with the new battery,  you might just experience extra heating in your laptop.

Anyway I wouldn't recommend buying a battery with higher voltage, look for another shop or just buy it online.

Refer to this question for more information [Using a 20V power block on a 19V notebook](https://superuser.com/questions/79818/using-a-20v-power-block-on-a-19v-notebook)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't buy a battery from a vendor who offered you another *voltage* for the same model. Laptop batteries are by *total capacity* NOT by voltage, and there's a good chance something is off if its a battery of different voltage.

The battery connectors for a laptop are *specific* to both the laptop brand and often the model as well. Your vendor seems fishy - a quick check shows the standard battery for the model - the [43R1955](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Essential/Lenovo-3000-Y410-Battery-Issue-Not-covered-in-MIGR-69671/td-p/91492) - see the post by Mark Lenovo  - is [10.8V](http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/catalog.workflow:item.detail?GroupID=38&Code=43R1955&current-category-id=4364BD0F20B94413B5AD6E684D2848E9&&hide_menu_area=yes#learnMore). ***DO NOT BUY A BATTERY OF ANY OTHER VOLTAGE***.

Comment: should be "DO NOT BUY A BATTERY OF ANY OTHER CHEMISTRY"

Comment: I would say at the very least, but something of that model. Also, the vendor dosen't seem very credible, and he needs to take his business elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

The battery *voltage* is fine.  The voltage on your OEM battery will be almost 13V when fully charged.

But, most batteries rated at 10.8V are Li-ion, those rated for 11.1V may be a different Li chemistry.  That's a complete show-stopper.  Your laptop charging circuit is designed for lithium ion batteries only, the logic for supplying the right current and detecting when the battery is fully charged will only work for Li-ion batteries.  A different chemistry will not behave exactly the same and may be overcharged, resulting in loss of mechanical integrity (i.e. battery bits all over the inside of your laptop) or a fire.

Although I was under the impression that Li batteries other than Li-ion aren't rechargeable... so probably your suggested replacement battery IS Li-ion just like the original.  But do verify that the chemistry matches, you want to be absolutely sure.

Pinout and power connector are of course critically important also -- having a battery connected backwards is no joke, either for the connected electronics, or the battery itself when it begins to charge.

Beyond electrical compatibility, there may or may not be some DMCA "smart battery" IC designed to prevent you from using a non-OEM battery.  But in that case it just won't work, nothing would be damaged.

Comment: again, Lenovo lists plenty of 11.1v batteries at Li-ion, not Li.  http://shop.lenovo.com/us/itemdetails/57Y6493/460/A5EB9DB8B66C416083597E397599C2A4 and http://shop.lenovo.com/us/itemdetails/57Y6266/460/50274E9573164120A96C8DFB00FC2AAF and http://shop.lenovo.com/us/itemdetails/0A36280/460/2D575BF5CD7E44E58547BFB52CC4F8E9

Comment: @BonGart, What this links contains I can't check, because whenever I go at that link, CPU usage becomes 100%.

Comment: Wait... you just said "All those batteries listed are 6 cell Li-ion, arranged with 3 in series. That means they are actually the same voltage, regardless of what the marketing team put on the box." so you are saying that it is OK for him to buy the 11.1v battery.  Since with the laptop battery, it only fits in one way and is impossible to put it in backwards... and who sells laptop batteries that are NOT rechargeable?

Comment: @BonGart: "connected backwards" is a matter of pinout, not physical reversal.  And it's still possible that this other battery is some other chemistry, so verifying that it is Li-ion is necessary.  But if this was designed as a third-party replacement for his family of laptop, then it is going to work.  Capacity might not be as good, thermal dissipation might not be as good, but it's probably an improvement over a two year old OEM battery.

Comment: @BenVoigt so, it being a matter of Pinout, it is a matter of manufacture and thus something that couldn't be determined by the end consumer by examination.  And if the battery is labeled Li-ion *and* 11.1v, what **EXACTLY** can the consumer do to determine chemistry before purchase?  You posted conflicting statements that 10.8 and 11.1 volt batteries were different chemistry, then later that they were the same regardless of labeling.  Which is it? And again, are you saying it is OK for him to get the 11.1v battery?

Comment: @BonGart: If the new pack is labelled Li-ion, it's the right chemistry.  The 11.1V battery may or may not work, but the *voltage* is not an issue like everyone else is saying.  The "10.8V" pack ranges from ~9 to ~13V depending on how much charge it is.

Comment: @BenVoigt I've got single cell Li-ion packs in front of me that state 3.6 AND 3.7 volts... and again, state they are Li-ion  Which is correct?  Are the ones that are Li-ion and 3.6v wrong?  Or are the ones that are 3.7 and Li-ion wrong?  What if both the 10.8 and 11.1 are labelled Li-ion?  What part does chemistry play then?

Comment: @BonGart: Have you not read a single thing I said about **the voltage changes as the battery discharges**?

Answer (score 0):

I was browsing for other information, but came across this thread and just wanted to drop in some details regarding batteries.  There's some great information on here already,  but I just had a few points make  :-)

The voltage difference between the 10.8 and the 11.1 batteries is negligable on any laptop.  There are changes in voltage in 'all' batteries as a natural part of what they are,  but beyond that,  batteries drop in power anyway as they discharge and only the circuit they are fitted to will decide if it's flat or not enough to work it (until the battery just cannot work any longer).

How does any laptop know the battery is going flat?  It tests voltage, amd when it finds it's getting too low,  it shuts down (or just goes off without warning - that's it's 2nd layer of auto-off,  1st level is a warning with OS shut down, 2nd level is full off to avoid lower voltage causing data problems while reading/writing.  To leave a circuit on a laptop struggling on a low battery with (for example) 7 volts,  could cause all kinds of data corruption, so the best thing is just instant off - then it's far more likely to just stop what it's doing.
Losing power slowly could cause a hard drive to smear data (in theory) across a drives platter ARRGGGHHH disaster!

It had been mentioned here about voltages on laptops being 19v,  so why is that?  Well this isn't mentioned much but is important to realise....

No circuit uses 19 volts.  Check on components and you instantly see 1v,  3v,  5v  9v,  12v etc.  Now where does your 19v laptop fit in then?

Well its for power and safety - no laptop uses more than 12v,  and most voltages are 5v,  or lower like 1.3 for CPU's and things like RAM.  If that 12v part needs power and your charger was 12v,  you'd be straining the whole circuit - that's no good.  So you have 19 volts,  to power the 12's,  and the 5's, and the other lower voltage parts,  and also,  of course,  that all important trickle charge to the battery (usually between 1.5 and 3.5 volts to charge things with, 3.5 being Fast Chargers - not used on laptops).

The bit to note is,  all the voltages are 'nearly' things.  None of it is precise at this level,  only things like RAM, data lines and CPU/GPU have 100% precision on voltages.  The rule on such techinical circuits is - always have a little more power than you need just in case,  but always have a protected voltage level anyway.

Consider the old fashioned and well used 7805 voltage regulator - you can slap 35+ volts into them,  and the just casually give you 5volts output and laugh while doing it.  That's your circuit protection from high voltages right there.

Laptops,  both battery and mainboard,  all have more modern versions of the same kind of thing inside them.

And also,  I happily put 11.1 or 14.4 batteries in several makes of laptops without any difference or problem.  As an example,  I have here on my desk a Packard Bell MIT-SABLE-C,  that happily uses either voltage, and I have 6 batteries I've been testing on it,  All do the same thing,  because the higher voltage battery has less amp,  so the power level at the end all stays about the same.

Comment: This does a nice job of discussing the voltage issue, but not the potential chemistry issue.

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference in a 10.8 and 11.1 volt battery for a laptop, some manufacturers choose to rate each cell higher or lower voltage but they are all the same actual usable voltage.