# Can I replace my 11.55 V laptop battery with 15.4 Volts

Tags: laptop, battery, voltage, hp

I have an HP 15-CX0056WM gaming it came with an SR03XL battery 3 cells 11.55 volts 52.5Wh
The replacement was SR04XL 4 cells 15.4 volts 54 Wh, is it okay to use it?
The vendor told me that this is the replacement for my battery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This same question was presented in the post
[Battery Upgrade Hp Pavilion gaming 15-CX0056WM](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Gaming-Notebooks/Battery-Upgrade-Hp-Pavilion-gaming-15-CX0056WM/td-p/7769913):

> Hello! i want to know my laptop came with a 52Wh battery SR03XL.
> this same laptop also comes with SR04XL which is a 70Wh.

This was the answer by an HP Support Agent :

> As per the product specifications for your device: [click here to check](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c06171851), the 3-cell, 52.5 Wh Li-ion polymer battery is what's compatible with your device, and the same is recommended, and I'm afraid I must let you know that HP does not recommend upgrades or hardware changes as the device is equipped with parts that perform at its optimal performance by design, that said, the upgradeable parts listed by HP articles are purely for your ease, as the decision to upgrade will be at your own discretion.

That said, I find SR04XL batteries recommended for your model in many
offers ([example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09NPT4HW6)),
which throws some doubt on whether the above advice was too cautious.

You can see the confusion in the post
[Can using higher rated battery damage device](https://superuser.com/questions/440564/can-using-higher-rated-battery-damage-device/440618)
from 2012, where you can find answers going both ways, for and against using
a higher voltage.

Finally, as the HP Support Agent said above, it's up to you to decide if
there is or isn't a risk.

Answer (score 8):

The replacement must have the same voltage (within very small limits). The vendor is incorrect. Take your business elsewhere.

Every place selling these batteries tells you these are not interchangeable in any way.

Comment: Most trustworthy seller(s) will also provide a list of devices that the battery is compatible.  *Now those lists are normally accurate, but obviously, the seller can't test every device so they are compatible on paper.* The point is that a trustworthy seller will provide this list and offer a return policy.  You should also avoid the "too good to be true" deals. There is a reason they are cheap, they are batteries from China, likely extremely old stock or the battery reports a fake capacity.

Comment: It's entirely possible that the laptop hardware supports two battery voltages. But yes, your answer applies in the general case.

Comment: I'd be also concerned with the charging -- if the charging electronics aren't prepared to produce the voltage or if they refuse to charge with more than the original nominal voltage 11.9V + x in order to prevent battery damage, they wouldn't fully charge the 15.4V battery. Do you know anything about how intelligent the charging is these days? Do laptops communicate with the battery, say, querying voltage, temperature and max charging current?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, absolutely. There are (were) ThinkPad models that could be used with various battery sizes. This battery, while internal, appears to use a similar connector.

Comment: @DanielB Well, battery *sizes* could be easily accommodated by dumb chargers ("charge at x V until full"). Voltages are more delicate.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: lithium-ion batteries pretty much rule out dumb chargers for fire safety reasons.  A damaged laptop battery taken on an airplane is a serious danger, and yes, Li batteries do catch fire at times other than being charged.  The only conceivable kind of dumb charging would be "charge at x Amps until y Volts", constant-current (and you detect "full" by the voltage across the battery), but real chargers need to back off the current when the battery is close to full. See [some V and A vs. time graphs on electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/619634)

Comment: @PeterCordes But the graph in the accepted answer represents a dumb charger: Charge essentially at constant voltage, except that you cap the current (which happens automatically with the right charger dimension).

Answer (score 1):

Normally that should be okay, since batteries output a relatively broad voltage range during their charge-discharge cycle anyways.
If the manufacturer says, that it's okay, it usually is okay. If not, then that's a warranty case.

Comment: How broad? That's 33% more than the original battery - quite a lot! And it's no coincidence that it's roughly ⅓: the original battery contains three 3.8V cells in series, while the replacement contains four. These are two completely different batteries!

Comment: For a single Li-Ion cell that would be 3.4V (empty) to 4.2V (full). But I highly suspect that a few of those contacts on the battery tell the charge controller how to treat it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same HP laptop and replaced my original sro3xl with a sro4xl. My original battery failed very quickly even though I never ran it on battery power. That's why I replaced it with a higher capacity and voltage battery with the hopes that it would last longer. So far the new battery has been working without any issues.

Comment: @Eddie_R Same here it's been working fine, but a notice that the past battery mostly failed because you're always charging it as you mentioned. The provider that I bought the new battery from highly recommended to always fully charge and then unplug it until it's around 10-20% this would extend it's life rather than keeping it constantly on power which would ruin it.

Answer (score 0):

I have to change my laptop HP Gaming Pavilion - 15-cx0001ng battery but I have both batteries available. I have 3 questions

1. did your laptop work normally after the battery changed to a higher capacity?
2. should you suggest buying a higher version of the battery
3. did your laptop work more in time compared to the older battery size?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please note - SE sites aren't disucssion boards, they are Q&A sites. Please take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and check out the [Help](https://superuser.com/help), at least the Asking and Answering -sections to learn how these sites work.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1175386)